# C++14 multithreading with group exclusive control and allowing concurrency inside the group

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, mutex

Hello I am having issue with one multithreading scenario:

Suppose I have 3 threads running on one type of function (named it node_a), 3 threads running on another type of functions (named it as node_b). each thread process different input data. They all access shared resource at some time.

Now I want to control the access of these threads: the 3 node_a threads are considered grp_a, and 3 node_b threads are considered grp_b. grp_a and grp_b are exclusive to each other accessing the shared resource, but grp_a and grp_b themself can run concurrently.

Here is my approach:

- I used two shared counter and control them using mutex
- I used shared_timed_mutex for exclusive and shared for the concurrency and exclusive

but it turns out I did not get the exclusive by printing out the timestamp each thread accessing the shared resources.

below is my C++14 code:

```
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::shared_timed_mutex mtx_a,mtx_b;
    atomic_int cnt_a{0},cnt_b{0};
    
    //code for node_a 
      mtx_a.lock_shared();//will block if lane holds the lock.+1
      bool a=0;
      while(cnt_a==0)  { //check if node_b threads are not running
        if(mtx_b.try_lock()) {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
          cnt_a++;//multiple threads change it, need protection!
          a=1;
        }
      }
    
    /*
    do some work here!!!!
    */
    
      mtx_a.unlock_shared();//-1
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        --cnt_a;
      }
      if(a){
        mtx_a.lock(); //block until all node_a threads are done
        mtx_b.unlock(); //can only be unlocked by current thread
        cnt_a=0;
        mtx_a.unlock();
      }
```

Similar code for the node_b

Anyone know what the issue is? Thanks

Comment: made some mistakes in the code, now fixed

Comment: while(cnt_a==0) is the correct one

Comment: Question is hard to understand, code is suspicious and it is hard to relate code to question.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few issues with your implementation.

- The use of timed mutexes is suspicious
- Whenever you have a thread that should wake up in reaction to some event, `condition_variable`s, `future`s or some other blocking synchronization should be involved. This is clearly not the time to be using a spinlock.
- Having to protect an atomic variable with a mutex is not a good sign.

I would suggest you instead think of your program as a state machine. It can be in one of three states:

1. not doing work (idle)
2. performing work from group a.
3. performing work from group b.

Whenever a thread wants to acquire the resource, whichever of theses states the program is currently in determines whether the thread is allowed to proceed or wait until the state goes back to idle.

So as far as synchronization resources go, you should need:

- An enum to track the current state of the state machine
- An `int` to know how many threads are currently "holding" the machine in its current state
- A `mutex` to synchronize access to them.
- A `condition_variable` to wait until the we go back to idle.

That should be **all** you need. Nothing more.

As far as a detailed implementation goes, it could look roughly like this: (using RAII so that clean bookending is guaranteed)

```cpp
// Which state the program is in.
enum class MyState {
  idle,
  a,
  b
};
MyState current_state = MyState::idle;

// How many threads of either a or b are holding the resource.
int current_state_count = 0;

// Protects access to current state and count
std::mutex state_mtx;

// Will be notified whenever the state goes back to idle.
std::condition_variable state_cv;


struct my_res_lock {
  my_res_lock(MyState s) {
    assert(s != MyState::idle);

    // Wait until the current state is either idle, or the one we want
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(state_mtx);
    state_cv.wait(lk, [s]{return current_state == MyState::idle || current_state == s;});

    // If we were in idle, transition to the desired state.
    current_state = s; 
  
    current_state_count += 1;
  }

  ~my_res_lock() {
    std::lock_guard lk(state_mtx);
    current_state_count -= 1;
    if( current_state_count == 0 ) {
      current_state = MyState::idle;

      // whenever we go back to idle, wake up all waiting threads.
      state_cv.notify_all();
    }
  }
};
```

```
// in thread A:
{
  my_res_lock res_lock(MyState::a);

  // do some work!
}

// in thread B:
{
  my_res_lock res_lock(MyState::b);

  // do some work!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Actually I spent almost a whole day on this yesterday and figured out what the problem is. The condition_variable to release the lock while wait and notify when work is done for one group. And my worked code is like this:

Comment: after I debugged and figured out the correct way and back to read your comments, it is really beneficial, thanks a lot for the education!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great answer, I managed to get it work correctly, but I could not post code in comment, so I put it here.

at the begin of thread_a

```
bool a=0;
{
  unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx_gpu);
  cv.wait(lck,[]{return cnt_b==0;});//while(!ready) cv.wait(lck)
  mtx_a.lock_shared();//will block if b holds the lock.+1. will cause deadlock here since mtx_b can also be acquired by thread_b
  if(cnt_a++==0) { //check if node_b threads are not running
    mtx_b.lock();
    a=1;
  }
}
```

at the end of thread_a:

```
mtx_a.unlock_shared();//-1
--cnt_a;
if(a){
  mtx_a.lock(); //block until all node_a threads are done
  mtx_b.unlock(); //can only be unlocked by current thread
  cnt_a=0;
  mtx_a.unlock();
  cv.notify_all();
}
```

The key point here is to use the condition_variable and wait for the notification while release the lock for other threads.